# Как получить текст из label в ячейке по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть `tableview`, в каждой ячейке имеется 2 `label`, 2 `textlabel` и 'image'
Все они парсятся с апи
Хотел бы выводить в консоль текст из этих элементов
Сделал что то типа такого

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let dn = arrData[indexPath.row]
     cell.fav_btn.tag = dn.id
     cell.fav_btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

При нажатии

```
@objc func checkMarkButtonClicked ( sender: UIButton) {
        print("button presed")
        let buttonTag = sender.tag
        print(buttonTag)

}
```

В консоль выводится id
Как можно передать текст из этих компонентов аналогично?
Или есть метод который будет лучше?

Comment: Вам важно ловить нажатие на кнопку или можно на ячейку?

Comment: Да нужно ловить на кнопку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишите по нормальному:

1) В классе вашей кастомной ячейки добавьте проперти блок:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var buttonAction: (() -> Void)?
}
```

2) В этом же классе (ячейки) добавьте Target для кнопки:

```
fav_btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Можете добавить кнопку через Storyboard тогда можно просто связать кнопку с экшеном из пункта 3.

3) Добавьте ваш метод в классе ячейки:

```
@objc func checkMarkButtonClicked (sender: UIButton) {
     if let myAction = buttonAction {
        myAction()
     }

}
```

3) В контроллере пропишите:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   // ваша логика

   cell.buttonAction = { [weak self] in
        self?.someMethod()
   }
}
```

4) Ну и добавьте `someMethod` в контроллере, он будет вызываться каждый раз когда вы будете нажимать на кнопку в ячейки.

Answer (score 0):

Если тексты для лейблов лежат в `arrData` и `dn.id` содержит уникальное значение, то в `checkMarkButtonClicked` можно в цикле пройтись по `arrData` и найти нужные данные по переданному `sender.tag`